# jQuery Isotope filter not sorting by date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Anyone familiar with https://isotope.metafizzy.co/ ?

I'm trying to sort by the date they last posted but it's sorting incorrectly. It's jumbling today, yesterday, and the months.

html

```
<div id="GROUP-<!-- |g_id| -->" class="ml-item ml-mem group-<!-- |g_id| -->" data-category="group-<!-- |g_id| -->" data-id="<!-- |id| -->">

<span class="lastposted"><!-- |last_post| --></span>

<button data-sort-value="lastposted">last posted by</button>
```

Here's the Isotope code:

```
// store filter for each group
var buttonFilters = {};
var buttonFilter = '*:not(.group-1, .group-3)';
// store filter for each group
var filters = {};
// quick search regex
var qsRegex;
var fcRegex;

// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.member-list').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.ml-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    fitRows: {
         gutter: 5      
},

 getSortData: {
    name: '.name',
    faceclaim: '.faceclaim',
    posts: '.posts parseInt',
    group: '[data-category]',
    lastposted:'[data-id] parseInt', 
    alias: '.alias'
 },

  sortAscending: {
    name: true,
    posts: false,
    lastposted: true,
    group: true,
    faceclaim: true,
    alias: true
  },
  filter: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var searchResult = qsRegex ? $(this).find('.name').text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
    var fcResult = fcRegex ? $(this).find('.faceclaim').text().match( fcRegex ) : true;
    var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
    return searchResult && fcResult && buttonResult;
 }
  });        

// bind filter button click
$('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', '.button', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  // get group key
  var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
  var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
  // set filter for group
  buttonFilters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
  // combine filters
  buttonFilter = concatValues( buttonFilters );
  // Isotope arrange
  $grid.isotope();
  updateFilterCount();
});

// bind sort button click
$('.sort-by-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  var sortValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-value');
  $grid.isotope({ sortBy: sortValue });
});

// bind filter button click
$('.button').on( 'click', '.button', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  // get group key
  var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
  var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
  // set filter for group
  buttonFilters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
  // combine filters
  buttonFilter = concatValues( buttonFilters );
  // Isotope arrange
  $grid.isotope();
  updateFilterCount();
});
// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('.quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
  qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
  $grid.isotope();
}) );
// use value of search field to filter
var $fcsearch = $('.fcsearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
  fcRegex = new RegExp( $fcsearch.val(), 'gi' );
  $grid.isotope();
}) );

// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
  var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
  $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues( obj ) {
  var value = '';
  for ( var prop in obj ) {
    value += obj[ prop ];
  }
  return value;
}

// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
  var timeout;
  threshold = threshold || 100;
  return function debounced() {
    clearTimeout( timeout );
    var args = arguments;
    var _this = this;
    function delayed() {
      fn.apply( _this, args );
    }
    timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold );
  };

}
```

It's jumbling (April 2 2023) or (Today/Yesterday with a time) and sort in a random order. I tried parseDate and then moved onto [data-id] parseInt which has gotten me the closest. Any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: Your example does not include any dates. Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows actual dates and the complete script you are using for sorting.

Comment: The dates are constantly changing depending on when the user's last post was. Which is why it pulls from the id variable. On the site the id variable is the last post date. Unfortunately that could be an actual date (May 25, 2023) in that format or it could be formatted as Today at 11:22pm or Yesterday at 1:15pm.

Answer (score 0):

Isotope's [getSortData](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html#getsortdata) requires values to be either a shortcut string, or a callback function to retrieve the data. Since your dates are in various formats that are not easily parseable, you must use a callback function.

Here is a function which should be able to sort the dates in the examples you gave ('May 25, 2023', 'Today at 11:22pm', 'Yesterday at 1:15pm'):

```js
let parseDate = function(s) {
    let r = null // assume
    console.log('Parsing ' + s)
    // let yesterday = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1).toDateString();

    tries = [ s, s.replace(/^Yesterday at/, yesterday + ', ').replace(/([0-9])(am|pm)$/, '$1 $2'), s.replace(/^Today at/, today + ', ').replace(/([0-9])(am|pm)$/, '$1 $2') ]
    for ( i=0; i < tries.length; i++ ) {
        let s2 = tries[i]
        console.log( '  Considering ' + s2)

        r = Date.parse(s2)
        if ( ! isNaN(r) ) {
            console.log( '    success with Date.parse(' + s2 + ')')
            break
        }

        const dt = new Date(s2)
        if (dt instanceof Date && !isNaN(dt)) {
            r = dt.getTime()
            if ( r ) {
                console.log( '    success with new Date(' + s2 + ')')
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isNaN(r) || r === null ) {
        console.log('ERROR parsing')
    }

    console.log('returning ' + r);
    return r;
}
```

It tries Javascript's [`Date()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) and [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) functions to parse the date string, along with some string manipulation to replace the leading 'Today at' or 'Yesterday at' with those actual dates. It also puts a space before the trailing 'am' or 'pm' since that's a requirement of `Date.parse()`.

I've left the `console.log()` calls so you can see the steps it takes and where it succeeds or fails.

Combining this with your `getSortData` object:

```
getSortData: {
    name: '.name',
    faceclaim: '.faceclaim',
    posts: '.posts parseInt',
    group: '[data-category]',
    lastposted: parseDate, 
    alias: '.alias'
},
```